# file transfer between s3 and ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, logging, scripting, amazon-s3

I want to automate transfer of tomcat log files from  micro instance to S3 account. However, all the scripts I find online use key pair in order to do this. I cant upload these key pair to the server for security reasons. Is it possible to create a shell script that automates moving of these log files into s3 without requiring to access .pem files ?

Comment: You would prefer global write access to your bucket, instead of storing a limited-permission keypair on your EC2 instance?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://s3tools.org/s3cmd ?

This will allow you to seamlessly copy files to your S3 bucket. You can use the rsync like sync option as well.

Comment: Note that you will need to keep your S3 credentials on the EC2 box.  You will need to keep them somewhere on the box to effect the transfer, after all.

Comment: If a separate IAM user is created for S3 access alone, fine-grained access control is possible -- http://andrewhitchcock.org/?post=325 Even though a key is used, IAM policies allows security to revoke it if compromised and provides limited access to specific bucket.